# What should I know in order to build an android app that downloads videos from youtube

Tags: android, youtube

I want to make an android app that does some downloading from Youtube or from any other website if possible. What are the things that I need to know in order to do it? I am  sort off an advanced beginner in android. Can you please give me the sequence of things that i need to learn in order to do it ex: learn javaScript then PHP ...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

just use a already script working for linux

youtube-dl is used in linux os to download youtube videos with specific 
attributes. so you can use it by runing a process in android

Comment: The idea is for me to learn something new, not just copy applications